# Is there no way concatenate two line into one statement?

Tags: c

Like

```
pri
ntf("hi");
```

I can use \ in macro but I think that doesn't work here :'(

Comment: Is there any reason you would ever want to do that?

Comment: any kind of whitespace is equal to the compiler: `foo ()`, `foo<TAB>()`, `foo<ENTER>()` are equivalent

Comment: Thank you there's no special reason sorry about typo

Comment: OT: You are aware that there are many "legal" position where a line can be splitted into multiple lines.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Using \ to continue C code across a line split was created so that C could be typed on punched cards (Hollerith cards) or in formats that emulated them, such as files with fixed-record-length formats. Are you using a keypunch to type your C code? Then use \ to continue the source code. Otherwise, avoid doing that. If you are trying to accomplish something else, then explain your goal and why you think concatenating lines can help, so that people can suggest appropriate solutions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I wanted to do because sometimes function's name is too long. There's no special purpose for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\`

```
pri\
ntf("hi");
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qj9b4r6qW)

From draft N1570 of the C standard, section 5.1.1.2 Translation phases:

> Each instance of a backslash character ( \ ) immediately followed by a new-line
> character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.

Comment: Note that this solution does not allow you to have any indentation in the following line. See my solution which does allow indentation.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yours won't work for templates taking multiple template arguments.

Comment: I reckon OP wants to split some long name to fit in line. Not something you'd usually do anyway

Comment: The question is tagged "c", not "c++". C does not have templates.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You're right. I totally missed that :D

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Using `\` will work, but you are not allowed to have any indentation in the following line. If you want to have indentation, you can do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONCATENATE(left,right) left##right

int main(void)
{
    CONCATENATE(
        pri,
        ntf("hi\n");
    )
}
```

Comment: But... how do I split `CONCATENATE` ?

Comment: @4386427: You also want to split the macro name `CONCATENATE` among two lines? If that name is too long, you can make it shorter. You can give it any name you want.

Comment: @4386427: If you want to split the actual macro definition among several lines, then you will have to use `\\` inside the macro definition.